# How to backup WhatsApp PC desktop

Tags: windows-10, backup, whatsapp

I'm using a WhatsApp PC app (Windows 10 desktop client). It is paired with my Android mobile app. Unfortunately, my mobile phone died suddenly (it switched off due to main board failure), and I can't retrieve any data from it anymore. Surprisingly to me, a WhatsApp PC app works fine, and I can still read old chats and write new ones.
It seems that I don't have a WhatsApp Android app backup anywhere in the cloud nor on an external memory card.
Is there any way to make a backup of WhatsApp PC desktop app that will enable me to transfer all chats to my new mobile app later on?

Comment: Have you checked through the application settings or documentation? If it doesn't have a built in option, first, it would have to store the content locally, and then that would have to either be in plain text or in a format where the encryption key is your WhatApp account, so that restoring the account would unencrypt the data.